# failed to open stream when saving image. Hostinger

Tags: php, android, hosting, fopen, web-hosting

I'm developing an Android App that sends an image encoded in base 64 to a PHP in the server (i'm using hostinger for the hosting), what i need to do is decode the String in base 64 and then save it into a folder in the ftp server, also in the DB. Everything is ok with inserting into the DB but when i try to save the image i get `fopen(places/): failed to open stream: Is a directory in home/HostingerID/public_html/appNameforStackOverflow/Comentario.php on line 27`

I don't kwnow if i have to change the path but my code is:

```
$decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'places/'.$image_name;
$file = fopen($path, 'wb'); //Line 27

$is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
fclose($file);
```

Maybe i need to change the permissions in the folder, if someone knows how to solve this problem please help.

Comment: Looks like you need to debug it. First thing I'd look at is $image_name. `var_dump($image_name);`

Comment: I'll try it, thanks. I  think made somthing wrong building the path and hostinger is a non factor because i tried the same code in localhost with same result. Sorry if my English is not that good

Comment: Do you know the answer for this as of today? I am facing the same issue at the moment